# How to read all CSV files from google cloud storage location into a single pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have gcs bucket and can list out all the files in the bucket using google colab like this:-

```
!gsutil ls gs://custom_jobs/python_test/
```

This lists out all the files which are:-

```
test_1.csv
test_2.csv
```

I can read a single file at a time like this:-

```
d = pd.read_csv('gs://custom_jobs/python_test/test_1.csv')
```

What I intend to do is read `test_1.csv` and `test_2.csv` in a single dataframe like we can do locally:-

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("/home/shashi/python_test/*.csv")

all_dat = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
  dat = pd.read_csv(file)
  all_dat = all_dat.append(dat, ignore_index=True)
```

How is this possible in `google colab` when my files are on `google storage bucket`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `ls` command in `gsutil`

**Ex:**

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['gsutil', 'ls', 'gs://custom_jobs/python_test/*.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

all_dat = pd.DataFrame()
for file in result.stdout.splitlines():
    dat = pd.read_csv(file.strip())
    all_dat = all_dat.append(dat, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution might be:

```
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
all_dat = pd.DataFrame()

storage_client = storage.Client()

# Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

for blob in blobs:
    dat = pd.read_csv("gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, blob.name)) 
    all_dat = all_dat.append(dat, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that I found was:-

```
files = !gsutil ls -r gs://custom_jobs/python_test/
```